Is there a way around "abort: option --config may not be abbreviated!"?
I was trying to add an alias to Mercurial that included use of the --config option.
But when I tried to run the alias, Mercurial spit out this error:

abort: option --config may not be abbreviated!

The alias I was trying to create was this:
[alias]
emptycommit = ci -m "empty commit" --config ui.allowemptycommit=1

(based on this)
Is there any way around this limitation?

The way to get around this error is to use Mercurial's syntax to have the alias run a shell command, and use hg itself as the shell command.
So in the example from the question, instead of this:
[alias]
emptycommit = ci -m "empty commit" --config ui.allowemptycommit=1

you would do this:
[alias]
emptycommit = !hg ci -m "empty commit" --config ui.allowemptycommit=1
              ^^^

I think you can use plain !hg as long as hg (or hg.exe on Windows) is in your path. Otherwise I have seen examples using !$HG instead to refer to an environment variable.

This approach of calling it via a shell command seems like a hack, but it's actually from the Mercurial documentation:

An alias can start with an exclamation point (!) to make it a shell
alias. A shell alias is executed with the shell and will let you run
arbitrary commands. As an example,
echo = !echo $@ will let you do hg echo foo to have foo printed in
your terminal. A better example might be:
purge = !$HG status --no-status --unknown -0 re: | xargs -0 rm -f


Thanks to a comment by @Torek which tipped me off to this.
